# Passport session authentication with websockets and Nest.js not authenticating

Tags: node.js, passport.js, nestjs

I can't get session authentication to work with socket.io and nest.js. In regular requests session guard works perfectly. The adapter itself seems to work. Console shows no errors, it's just not authenticating.

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const sessionSecret = configService.get('SESSION_SECRET');
  const MongoUri = configService.get('MONGO_URI');
  const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: sessionSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: MongoUri }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 60 * 1000 * 60 * 24 * 14,
    },
  });
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true,
  });
  app.use(sessionMiddleware);
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SessionAdapter(sessionMiddleware));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

SessionAdapter

```
export class SessionAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  private session: express.RequestHandler;

  constructor(session: express.RequestHandler) {
    super(session);
    this.session = session;
  }

  create(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): Server {
    const server: Server = super.create(port, options);

    const wrap = (middleware) => (socket, next) =>
      middleware(socket.request, {}, next);

    server.use((socket, next) => {
      socket.data.username = 'test'; //passing random property to see if use method is working
      next();
    });
    server.use(wrap(this.session));
    server.use(wrap(passport.initialize()));
    server.use(wrap(passport.session()));
    return server;
  }
}
```

Event.gateway.ts

```
@WebSocketGateway(80, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  },
})
export class EventsGateway implements OnGatewayConnection {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  // @UseGuards(AuthenticatedGuard)
  @UseGuards(WsAuthenticatedGuard)
  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleMessage(client: any, payload: any): string {
    console.log(payload);
    console.log(client.username);
    console.log(client.request.user);
    client.emit('answer', 'Hello client');
    return payload;
  }

  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log(client.data.username); //console is showing 'test' as it suppose to
    console.log('user connected');
  }
}
```

ws.authenticated.guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class WsAuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const client = context.switchToWs().getClient();
    const request = client.request;
    console.log(request.isAuthenticated());
    return request.isAuthenticated(); //guard returns false
  }
}
```

authenticated.guard.ts (guard for regular requests)

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Console logged request shows that session and passport is initialized, but there is no user property from passport.session()

```
sessionID: 'Mu7DiHk_eNZ4S-ujFhnXOOqOl7EwLLFe',
  session: Session {
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      _expires: 2021-08-21T15:53:24.871Z,
      originalMaxAge: 1209600000,
      httpOnly: true
    }
  },
  _passport: {
    instance: Authenticator {
      _key: 'passport',
      _strategies: [Object],
      _serializers: [Array],
      _deserializers: [Array],
      _infoTransformers: [],
      _framework: [Object],
      _userProperty: 'user',
      _sm: [SessionManager],
      Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
      Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
      Strategy: [Function],
      strategies: [Object]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to pass `app` to the constructor of `IoAdapter`:

```js
constructor(session: express.RequestHandler, app: INestApplicationContext) {
  super(app);
  this.session = session;
}
```

And initalize the adapter as follows:

```js
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SessionAdapter(sessionMiddleware, app));
```

And least in my case this was the missing bit.

Answer (score 1):

Its may be obvious, but I overlooked. In my case I had to enable credentials option within cors options both server side and client side.

Otherwise passport can't access session cookie.

---

Example with Socket.io:

- clientside:

```js
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { withCredentials: true });
```

- at NestJS

```js
@WebSocketGateway({
   cors: {
      origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
      credentials: true,
   },
})
export class XYGateway { ... }
```

Note that you must provide an exact origin without a wildcard symbol when the request's credentials mode is included.